# Let $X$ be a metric space, and let $f:X \to X$ be a $k$ contraction. Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $d(f^n(x),f^{n+1}(x)) \leq k^nd(x,f(x))$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space, and let $f:X \to X$ be a $k$ contraction. Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $d(f^n(x),f^{n+1}(x)) \leq k^nd(x,f(x))$.

By definition, because $f(x)$ is a $k$-contraction, $d(f(x),f(y)) \leq kd(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$.

I also have this theorem I could employ? Because $f$ is $k$-contracted, then we know $f$ has a unique fixed point at $x_0$ and for all $x \in X$, the iterated map on $f$ based at $x$ converges to $x_0$.

Comment: Done! What else do you want me to do?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Answer (score 3):

Apply your last sentence $n$ times.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of contraction, 
\begin{equation}
d(f^{n}(x), f^{n+1}(y)) \leq kd(f^{n-1}(x), f^{n}(y)) \leq k^2 d(f^{n-2}(x), f^{n-1}(y)) \leq ... \leq k^{n-1}d(f(x), f^2(y)) \leq k^n d(x, f(y)).
\end{equation}